# How to pass field values to apex class by command button?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to pass id field value to apex class to delete that row by using command button.

**Class:**

```
public class search_delete
{
public string id {get;set;}
public list<account> acc{get;set;}
public search_delete()
{
    acc = new list<account>();        
    acc = [SELECT id,name,phone,industry from account];

}
public void delete_record()
{

acc = [SELECT name,phone,industry from account where id = :id];

delete acc;
}
}
```

**VP:**

```
<apex:page controller="search_delete" >
 <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
         <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>         
         <apex:column >
             <apex:commandButton value="Delete" Action="{!delete_record}">
                 <apex:param name="accId" value="{!a.id}"/>
             </apex:commandButton>
         </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>     
 </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Now i need to pass id value to apex class from Vp page by the click of delete button.
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVRA.png)

Comment: Add rerender in your commandbutton.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the $Action.SObjectName.Delete command

```
<apex:column headerValue="Action">
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Delete, a.Id)}">
        Delete
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reRender and an assignTo attribute, as below, to get this to work:

```
         <apex:commandButton value="Delete" Action="{!delete_record}" reRender="form">
             <apex:param assignTo="{!id}" name="accId" value="{!a.id}"/>
         </apex:commandButton>
```

Also, to make the page redraw correctly, change your form to have an id:

```
<apex:form id="form">
```

Comment: Great Work, Can you help me to resolve my another question 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237892/create-formula-field-based-on-report-created-date